# How to handle new realm app users confirmation with a MongoDB Function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, realm

I tried to create an HTTP Endpoint with a Function, where I tried to install realm-web, I add the `realm-web` dependency successfully, but when I try to import it with

```
import * as Realm from "realm-web";
```

It gives me this response:

> error:
> failed to execute source for 'node_modules/realm-web/dist/bundle.cjs.js': TypeError: Cannot access member 'name' of undefined
> at node_modules/realm-web/dist/bundle.cjs.js:4260:13(847)

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? How does import works within a function? It should give you a syntax error.

Comment: It's basically the first line, right above exports = function....

Comment: did you try to save it?

Comment: I mean, all docs use `require`, so it would be fair to assume no modules. And, frankly, having requeres **within** export function raises questions about internal implementation.

Comment: I know @AlexBlex asked for a screenshot but please also include code as *text* in the question. That way if we need to duplicate it, we can copy and paste instead of retyping the whole thing. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, if you remove all of the code in the function except the first import line, does it still generate an error?

Comment: @Jay It's very easy to reproduce. Just put the `import`  statement to any/empty/default function and click "run" as on the screenshot without saving, as it won't pass linter validation.

Comment: if you want to reproduce, just install the dependency, add the import line and try to run, that's all you need to do

Comment: Since the issue is `realm-web` itself (which it appears to be), there's nothing we can do about it here on SO as and this should be filed as a bug report with Realm as they will need to address it internally. Did you also [Link a Datasource](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/mongodb/#link-a-data-source)?